# Which graph shows how the power $P$ dissipated in the load resistor varies with the resistance of the load resistor?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

[image]

^ question

Which graph shows how the power P dissipated in the load resistor varies with the resistance of the load resistor?

The answer is A but what I need help in understanding is why. From what I understand the answer can't be A because since R increases, the power dissipated increases as $P = I^2R$ and the current $I$ is the same for both resistances because in series the current is equal for both components whenever it changes,  so the line has an increasing gradient -  **but what exactly is the reason that causes the gradient on the graph to decrease again?** If the resistance keeps increasing and so does the power dissipated across it, just why does it randomly start decreasing? I feel like $E=V+Ir$ has to do something with it, but using it only lets me infer that $Ir = E-V$ thus with increasing terminal potential difference there's a smaller value for the lost volts. How that's supposed to help me exactly I don't understand.

I'll appreciate any response.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I've got an answer (if the working is incorrect that would invalidate this answer, in that case please leave a comment, thanks).

Power dissipated:

$P = I^2R$

$I = V/R_{T} = 12/(2+R)$

$P = 12/(2+R) * R$

choosing values 0.5 through 4 for $R$ we can infer by the results that the gradient should increase and that the maximum of the graph should be at $R = 2$ and after that (for values of $R$ where $R > 2$) the magnitude of the total power dissipated decreases hence the gradient on a graph would then decrease.